# Using interface in service contract instead of concrete type in WCF

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, json

I have WCF service operation which accepts Interface as a input type. While calling this service operation from jQuery Ajax,  I'm getting message "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error". The jQuery code works file if the input type is concrete class. Please tell me if there is any way to achieve this kind of implementation.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]    
public class TestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(User))]
    public void SetUser(IUser request)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in WCF, so the question is what is the real exception message. Are you debugging the app when you make the call to the service using jQuery?

To get more information in the actual exception you should use svcTraceViewer. If you've not used svcTraceViewer before then you may want to look at a blog post on my blog

[svcTraceViewer - Debugging WCF Sevices](http://www.matlus.com/svctraceviewer-debugging-wcf-sevices/)

Comment: The exception is coming before call going to server as it is not able to resolve the input type. Hence svcTraceView does not show any details.

Comment: Well the server is the one trying to resolve the method parameters, so you should see an error in svcTraceViewer (provided you've set up tracing correctly). This is a server side error. It's just that WCF does not send the real exception messages to the client. Either way, without knowing the actual exception it's going to be a hit and mis thing.

Comment: I'm getting "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'ProcessFlowController.IUser'" message in svcTraceViewer.

Comment: There you have it. You now know what the error is so you can resolve it.

Comment: But how would I send the type information from javascript as I'm making ajax call?

Comment: you don't send the type information from the client. The service is supposed to be able to figure this out and it normally does if things are set up correctly. I'm not sure what is really going on but the error message is the clue.

Comment: Can you please help in setting up the service? I have not modified any settings in web.config, it has the default setting whatever added when we add the WCF service.

Comment: Can you try something please? Write a service method that send out an instance of IUser. See if that works. Also, why the pressing need to have the method except and interface and not a concrete class? You can always pass on the parameter to a method that expects an interface.

Comment: @Shiv: I don't believe you can serialize an interface. Are you sure? Have any references?

Comment: John, in the past I've used the NetDataContractFormatSerializer to do this. But it's been a while since I've used the built-in serialization mechanisms (DataContractSerializer etc.), so I can't be sure of what works "out of the box" versus what works for me. I do serialize interfaces (on the way out) but on the way in they are a concrete type (so the correct OperationContract gets called. Either ways, it's one heck of a complicated route for almost no benefit, which is why I asked about the pressing need in my last comment.